# Android: ImageView getting negative width

Tags: android

I'm not sure why, but when I set the width of an imageview (called c), it returns a negative value.
ivPiano is also an imageView.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = llPiano.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onGlobalLayout() { 
            llPiano.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
            c.setTop(ivPiano.getTop());
            c.setLeft(ivPiano.getLeft());
            ShowMessageLong(ivPiano.getWidth());
            c.getLayoutParams().width = ivPiano.getWidth();
            c.getLayoutParams().height= ivPiano.getHeight();
            c.bringToFront();
            ShowMessageLong(c.getWidth());
        } 
    });
```

ShowMessageLong() just creates and shows a toast. The first time (ivPiano's width) shows 1200, then second one (c's width) returns -22. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That's not a real function